# JavaScript.push() insere variavel ao invez do valor da variável

Tags: javascript

estou com problema com esse codigo:

**saida esperada:**

```
detalhes:[{
    01: 4570.00,
    02: 4301.68,
    03: 650.00,
    12: 700.00,
}]
```

**realidade:**

```
0:[{
  {
    mes: 4570.00,
  },
  {
    mes: 4301.68,
  },
  {
    mes: 650.00,
  },
  {
    mes: 700.00,
  }
}]
```

não entendi porque ele não imprime o valor da variavel `mes`

```js
var datas = {
        "venda_detalhes": {
            "2018-01-10 00:00:00": "4570.00",
            "2018-02-15 00:00:00": "4301.68",
            "2018-03-17 00:00:00": "650.00",
            "2017-12-22 14:21:31": "700.00"
        }
      };
detalhes = [];
for (let prop in datas.venda_detalhes) {
    let data = new Date(prop);
    let mes = (data.getMonth() +1);
    let value = datas.venda_detalhes[prop];

    detalhes.push({mes : value});                        
}

console.log(detalhes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre que está a construir um objeto tem de definir pares de chave e valor. Em que a chave é na verdade um nome, o nome do campo ao qual quer associar o valor.

```
let pessoa1 = {
    nome: "Marcos",
    idade: 23
};
```

Repare que nome e idade são na verdade `strings`, propriedades do objeto e não valores que vem de variáveis.

No seu caso se pretende construir o nome de um campo com valores que vem de variáveis pode faze-lo utilizando o operador indexação por exemplo:

```
let var1 = "desportivo";
pessoa1[var1] = "Ferrari";
```

Aplicando isso ao seu exemplo:

```js
var datas = {
        "venda_detalhes": {
            "2018-01-10 00:00:00": "4570.00",
            "2018-02-15 00:00:00": "4301.68",
            "2018-03-17 00:00:00": "650.00",
            "2017-12-22 14:21:31": "700.00"
        }
      };
      
detalhes = [];
datasMes = {}; //objeto para acumular todas as datas

for (let prop in datas.venda_detalhes) {
    let data = new Date(prop);
    let mes = (data.getMonth() +1);
    let value = datas.venda_detalhes[prop];
    datasMes[mes] = value; //mais uma propriedade no objeto
}

detalhes.push(datasMes); //juntar o objeto ao array

console.log(detalhes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpretando o código:
1 - O array 'detalhes' está recebendo um object a cada iteração
2 - O object está sendo construído com uma propriedade de nome 'mes' com um valor 'number'

Achei essa saída prática mas editaria o object dentro de detalhes para incluir o 'value'; iria gerar uma saída assim

```
0:[{
  {
    mes: 1
    value: 4570.00,
  },
  {
    mes: 2
    value: 4301.68,
  },
  {
    mes: 3
    value: 650.00,
  },
  {
    mes: 12
    value: 700.00,
  }
}]
```

Isso permite uma nova iteração sem precisar do for... in... dentro das propriedades.

Tenho esse código que gera a saída desejada.

```js
var datas = {
        "venda_detalhes": {
            "2018-01-10 00:00:00": "4570.00",
            "2018-02-15 00:00:00": "4301.68",
            "2018-03-17 00:00:00": "650.00",
            "2017-12-22 14:21:31": "700.00"
        }
      };
detalhes = [];
detalhesDoMeses = {};
for (let prop in datas.venda_detalhes) {
    let data = new Date(prop);
    let mes = (data.getMonth() +1);
    let value = datas.venda_detalhes[prop];
    
    detalhesDoMeses[mes] = value;                         
}

detalhes.push(detalhesDoMeses);

console.log(detalhes);
```

A diferença entre os dois é que no primeiro o array recebe objects (não é o esperado), no segundo um object só.

Depois procure algo sobre objects vs arrays em javascript, são estruturas bem semelhantes.